# Check if a column is incremental in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I like to check whether a specific column in postgresql is incremental or not. For example, I have 2 columns named id and created_at.

```
select id, created_at from task_consumption_results order by created_at asc;
```

and

```
select id, created_at from task_consumption_results order by id asc;
```

should yield the exact same results. The column id is definitely auto increment, and I'd like to check whether created_at is also incremental. Any helps would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`.  For instance, to get the rows where `id` is greater than the "previous" `id` based on `created_at`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(id) over (order by created_at) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id > id
```